# How to override / update an s3 file that is a different file type?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm generating a unique id for each s3 file.

then, i'm saving the s3 response url, which contains the key and file / type to the database.

When I have, for instance a user update their profile photo, and it was first a jpg, but now it's a png -- how do I overwrite that photo / update the users photo?

What's the best way to go about this?

It has to be the exact same file name (including the file type) to overwrite it, correct?

---

This is my code in Nodejs.

basically, I make a unique id and save that with the path as the S3 key.

Later, I save the key to the database for a specific user.

```
    exports.signing = function(req, res) {
    var request = req.body;

    //assigns unique id to each photo name
    function generateUUID() {
     var d = new Date().getTime();
     var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
         var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
         d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
     });
     return uuid; };

    var fileName =  generateUUID();

    var path = request.folder + fileName + request.type;

    var readType = 'private';

    var expiration = moment().add(5, 'm').toDate(); //15 minutes

    var s3Policy = {
        'expiration': expiration,
        'conditions': [{
                'bucket': aws.bucket
            },
            ['starts-with', '$key', path],
            {
                'acl': readType
            },
            {
              'success_action_status': '201'
            },
            ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', request.type],
            ['content-length-range', 2048, 10485760], //min and max
        ]
    };

    var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
    var base64Policy = new Buffer(stringPolicy, 'utf-8').toString('base64');

    // sign policy
    var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', aws.secret)
        .update(new Buffer(base64Policy, 'utf-8')).digest('base64');

    var credentials = {
        url: s3Url,
        fields: {
            key: path,
            AWSAccessKeyId: aws.key,
            acl: readType,
            policy: base64Policy,
            signature: signature,
            'Content-Type': request.type,
            success_action_status: 201
        }
    };
    res.jsonp(credentials);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your scenario, you will need to save a canonical reference to the user profile photo in a database. This value is called the [S3 object key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys)

Please note that when you say:

> i'm saving the s3 response url, which contains the key and file / type
>   to the database

you are referring to the data [S3 object key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys). An object key (or key name) uniquely identifies the object in a bucket. Therefore what you are saving in the DB is the [S3 object key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys). S3 object keys will look like these examples:

```
John/profile.jpg
Private/25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395332f0223.jpg
25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0225.gif
/app/profiles/25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0226.png
```

These are the types of values you will associate with the user profile. So when uploading a new user profile picture:

1. delete the old object key (if it exists)
2. upload the new one
3. and update the DB with the new key

Comment: I notice the photo will still show if I create it (and the key) without appending the file type to the end (.jpg , png, etc). 

curious if you know any limitations to not adding the file type?

perhaps older browsers or phones will not display the referenced image?

Comment: It would be unusual to not include the file extension in the key. However the browser will look for the MIME type listed in the Content-type header in the response from the HTTP server. If the content type is image/jpeg, or png, gif, etc it will render the image correctly, even if there is no file extention.  Make sure and upload the image to S3 with the correct MIME type.  A good S3 uploader may require the extension of the file in order to know what content type header to write to S3.

Comment: random follow up question. What's the best way to display the image on a website? Prefix the  <img src> with the beginning of the url, then concatenate it with the saved key in the database?